# How do I change the color of a row in ListView depending on what is on each row?

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a listview in my SolutionActivity class in Android. The Adapter fills the list with elements based on results from user input in another activity. The listview's can only have two values, "true" or false". I have searched all over the web and I see a lot of 'getView' methods being called in a custom adapter class however I tried to implement this but I couldn't figure out how? Do I create a seperate class just for my Adapter? Or can I add it in the end of my SolutionActivity? And how do I use the getView method? Anyway this is my code...

```
public void setUserResults() { //displays the bit combination and users services in the listviews
    ListView serviceNames = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listofservices);
    ListView bitResults = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.bitresults);
    UserInputSet userInputSet = UserInputSet.getInstance();
    List<String> userServices = MainActivity.dimensions;
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            userServices);
    ArrayAdapter<Boolean> bitArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Boolean>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            CustomUseCase.getBestComboArray());
    serviceNames.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    bitResults.setAdapter(bitArrayAdapter);
}
```

I want to set the row green if the value of 'getBestComboArray()' is true, else red if it is false. Can anyone suggest a good solution to this? Thank you

Comment: you have to use custom adapter for that

Comment: @AliAhsan yeh i know that, I just don't know how to implement it like I said in the question.

Comment: okay let me add code in answer

Answer (score 2):

Create Custom adapter class

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private List<Boolean> greenColor;
private List<String> Words;

public CustomAdapter(Activity context, List<String> words,List<Boolean> layoutcolor)
{
                   Words = words; 
            this.context = context
            greenColor = layoutcolor;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    if(view==null)
        view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);


    View view1 = view.findViewById(R.id.colorContainer);

    if(layoutColor.get(position)){
    view1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
     }else{
            view1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
          }


    TextView textViewdefault = (TextView)    view.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    textViewdefault.setText(words.get(position));

    return view;

}
}
```

Create layout with name list_item and change with views you wanted to show on each row

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/colorContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:text="text1"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    />



</LinearLayout>
```

And then set call the adapter to list view

```
CustomAdapter <String> bitArrayAdapter = new CustomAdapter <String>(this,  TextViewList, // TextViewList is the list of text for textview of each row
CustomUseCase.getBestComboArray());

bitResults.setAdapter(bitArrayAdapter);
```

And you are good to go :)

Comment: let me know if you have still any issues

Comment: i am going to test it now, sorry for the late response

Comment: Hi, I get "there is no default constructor in ArrayAdapter<String>" error on the constructor you gave

Comment: also "this.context" is invalid in the customadapter class